# Cyclical dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas DF which looks like this:
[dataframe image]

[image: 1]

And I want to add a date column here which goes from '2019-01-01' to '2019-12-01' since each row here is a month's observation. Is there a simple command that can get this job done? So far I have tried

```
pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', end='2020-01-01', freq='M')
```

but this throws an error saying:

> Length of values (12) does not match length of index (6876)

I am looking for something that looks like:

```
state1   district1   2019-01-01
state1   district1   2019-02-01
...
state1   district1   2019-12-01
state1   district2   2019-01-01
state1   district2   2019-02-01
...
```

Even though I know this is a possible solution, I strongly want to avoid splitting this into several 12 row data frames and (left) joining the date column to each of them.

Comment: remove screenshot and procide sample data as code ( a minimal reproducible sample code/data)

Comment: `pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', end='2019-12-31', freq='MS').tolist() * df.groupby(['ADM1_NAME', 'ADM2_NAME']).ngroups`  works only if your df is formatted strictly 12 rows per group and sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat stringent implementation would be

```py
# dictionary of index -> month

months = dict(enumerate(pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', periods=12, freq='MS')))

# Now create an enumeration of each item and map it to its month

df['month'] = df.groupby("ADM2_NAME").transform("cumcount").map(months)
```

If the dataframe is very long, I would work with `pd.merge` instead for higher performance, but that requires some more effort to retain the order of the input, and I don't think it's required to have a more advanced solution.

Note I'm using `freq="MS"` to get the first of every month.

Comment: Works for some, adds the value 'NaT' for others. More precisely, it just adds the date for the first district of each state, the others are left as 'NaT'

Comment: You say each 'ADM2_NAME' value has exactly 12 observations. So adjust the code to juse ADM2_NAME then

Answer (score 1):

The following only assumes that the rows of each (`state`, `district`) group are sorted chronologically. It should work even if some groups don't have all the observations from the last few months.

```
dates = ( 
    pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', end='2020-01-01', freq='M'))
      .rename('date')
)

df['date'] = (
    df.groupby(['ADM1_NAME', 'ADM2_NAME'])
      .cumcount()
      .to_frame('date_idx')
      .merge(dates, left_on='date_idx', 
             right_index=True, how='left')['date']
)
```